# How to combine duplicate data and get the largest values

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, ranking, sumifs

I have a list of data example below:

```
> COLUMN A  | COLUMN B  |COLUMN C    
APPLE       |2          |RED  
PEAR        |3          |GREEN  
APPLE       |4          |RED  
BANANA      |5          |YELLOW  
BANANA      |5          |YELLOW
```

I have a work sheet where i want to list the top 3 fruits combined and ranked from 1,2,3

```
Example below:  
(Fruit Name) |(Count)  
 1. Banana   |10  
 2. Apple    |6  
 3. Pear     |3
```

Could you please advice on what formula i will need to use

I have tried to use the large(if(...,row(a1) formula but it isnt giving me the correct results based on the criterias.

Thank you

Comment: Which formula(s) have you tried? Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: Use SUMIF(), will do that count.

Comment: i want to make the sheet as neat as possible so dont want to use pivot as i will be updating the sheet on a regular...want to make it automated ...=IFERROR(LARGE(IF('Fruitsdata'!$A$2:$A$1048575=top10!$C$22,IF('fruitsData'!$L$2:$L$1048575=top10!$C$24,IF('fruitsdata'!$K$2:$K$1048575=$C$23,'fruitsdata'!$F$2:$F$1048575))),ROW(A2)),"")

Answer (score 0):

I would insert that into a pivot table and then select the top 3 items by the sum.

Another way is using Excel's Data/[Remove Duplicates] to get all the different fruits. Then next to each fruit you can do sumif() to get the total per fruit. Finally, I would use the rank formula to know which are my top 3 and just filter them out. [image: pivot picture]

By the way, the cleanest solution is a pivot table. It will automatically refresh with your new data, just like if you had it based on formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution, an issue will be fruits with the same count:

[image]

Expanding it is good exercise for you...